# Select min/max from group defined by one column as subgroup of another - SQL, HPVertica

Tags: sql, max, min, vertica, partition

I'm trying to find the min and max date within a subgroup of another group.  Here's example 'data'

```
ID   Type  Date
1     A    7/1/2015
1     B    1/1/2015
1     A    8/5/2014
22    B    3/1/2015
22    B    9/1/2014
333   A    8/1/2015
333   B    4/1/2015
333   B    3/29/2014
333   B    2/28/2013
333   C    1/1/2013
```

What I'd like to identify is - within an ID, what is the min/max Date for each block of similar Type? So for ID # 333 I want the below info:

```
A: min & max = 8/1/2015
B: min = 2/28/2013
   max = 4/1/2015
C: min & max = 1/1/2013
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to identify only uninterrupted groupings of Type within a grouping of ID. For ID #1, I need to keep the two 'A' Types with separate min/max dates because they were split by a Type 'B', so I can't just pull the min date of all Type A's for ID #1, it has to be two separate instances.

What I've tried is something like the below two lines, but neither of these accurately captures the case mentioned above for ID #1 where Type B interrupts Type A.

```
Max(Date) OVER (Partition By ID, Type)

or this:
Row_Number() OVER (Partition By ID, Type ORDER BY Date DESC)
  ,then selecting Row #1 for max date, and date ASC w/ row #1 for min date
```

Thank you for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Anyone able to provide any suggestions for a potential solution?  Even if you don't have the full answer, any advice on how to think about this would be really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you want the min/max values for an id/type grouped using a descending date sort, but the catch is that you want them based on clusters within the id by time.

What you can do is use [`CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/TimeSeries/CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENTAnalytic.htm) to tag the rows on change of type, then use that in your `GROUP BY` on a standard min/max aggregation.

This would be the intermediate step towards getting to what you want:

```
select ID, Type, Date,
  CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(Type) OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date desc) cce
from mytable
group by ID, Type, Date
order by ID, Date desc, Type

ID  Type Date                   cce
1   A    2015-07-01 00:00:00    0
1   B    2015-01-01 00:00:00    1
1   A    2014-08-05 00:00:00    2
22  B    2015-03-01 00:00:00    0
22  B    2014-09-01 00:00:00    0
333 A    2015-08-01 00:00:00    0
333 B    2015-04-01 00:00:00    1
333 B    2014-03-29 00:00:00    1
333 B    2013-02-28 00:00:00    1
333 C    2013-01-01 00:00:00    2
```

Once you have them grouped using CCE, you can do an aggregate on this to get the min/max you are looking for grouping on cce.  You can play with the order by at the bottom, this ordering seem to make the most sense to me.

```
select id, type, min(date), max(date)
from (
select ID, Type, Date,
  CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(Type) OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date desc) cce
from mytable
group by ID, Type, Date
) x
group by id, type, cce
order by id, 3 desc, 4 desc;

id  type min                    max
1   A    2015-07-01 00:00:00    2015-07-01 00:00:00
1   B    2015-01-01 00:00:00    2015-01-01 00:00:00
1   A    2014-08-05 00:00:00    2014-08-05 00:00:00
22  B    2014-09-01 00:00:00    2015-03-01 00:00:00
333 A    2015-08-01 00:00:00    2015-08-01 00:00:00
333 B    2013-02-28 00:00:00    2015-04-01 00:00:00
333 C    2013-01-01 00:00:00    2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH.  I'm sorry it took me quite a while to get back to this, but yes your solution worked and I really appreciate the help.  I didn't know about conditional_change_event and that has been very helpful.  Thanks again!